# Let $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$, prove that $f(\mathbb{C})= \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I've been on this for a while and would appreciate some help. I need to prove that if a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C \to C}$ satisfies $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z|\to \infty$, then $f(\mathbb{C})= \mathbb{C}$.

Here's what I have so far. I know that if I can show that $f(\mathbb{C})$ is open closed and nonempty then $f(\mathbb{C})= \mathbb{C}$. It's obviously not empty since it has at least one value since its the image of a function. It is also open by open mapping theorem since $\mathbb{C}$ is open and $f$ is a non-constant function, $f$ sends open sets to open sets. Finally to show $f(\mathbb{C})$ is closed I've tried to show that $\mathbb{C}\setminus f(\mathbb{C})$ is open but to no avail. I've also tried to show that $f$ contains all its limit points but again unable. Could someone help? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your post to conform to the standards of the site. Please consult the MathJax tutorial at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Comment: This won't work unless $f$ is holomorphic / analytic.

Comment: Sorry yes f is entire, ie holomorphic on. C

Comment: In answer to your comment below: work out why your argument (combined with my closedness one) don't work for $e^z$.

Comment: Thanks chappers I will try it

Answer (score 3):

Note that this proposition is a generalization of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (every complex polynomial has a complex root). A well known proof of this theorem makes use of Liouville's theorem. The proof is as follows:

Suppose $f$ is not surjective. Then $\exists a \in \mathbb{C} \setminus f(\mathbb{C})$. Consider the analytic function $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)-a}$, defined over the whole $\mathbb{C}$. Then, by your hypothesis on $f$, you have that $g(z) \to 0$ for $|z| \to \infty$. Hence $g$ is bounded, hence constant by Liouville. And this is a contradiction.

Comment: You need to avoid having $f(z)$ get arbitrarily close to $a$ as well.

Comment: @Chappers Why? There is $R>0$ such that $|g(z)|\le 1$ for $|z|>R$. The set $D=\{z:|z|\le R\}$ is compact, so $|g|$ is bounded on $D$. Therefore $g$ is bounded. On the other hand, this is the same argument as Olivier's.

Comment: @Chappers Continuity gives you this.

Comment: @Chappers I don't think so. The hypothesis on $f$ are enough to conclude that $f(z)$ does not get arbitrarily close to $a$.

Comment: Yes, you need to stick an open ball around $a$ where $f(z)$ can't go, which you do with continuity.

Comment: @Chappers Of course a “well behaved” function would go arbitrarily near to $a$, but the proof is by contradiction, so it's expected that $f$ has funny properties, isn't it?

Comment: Why? This proof was so easy to follow but if it never reaches a then its still valid as denominator is not 0?

Comment: The point is that the denominator could get arbitrarily close to zero if $f(z)$ gets arbitrarily close to $a$, so $g$ would not be bounded. This doesn't happen because $f$ is a continuous map from a closed set, so its image is closed. Hence the complement of the image is open and you can find an open ball (radius $r$, say) about $a$ that $f$ does not enter, so $|g|$ is bounded by $1/r$.

Comment: Wait so youre saying since C is closed, then f(C) is also closed since f is continuous? Then I could just use my proof since I already showed f(C) was open and non empty?

Comment: Also perhaps this is a silly question but doesnt louisville say that if f is bounded above then it is a constant? Here were using the fact that it is bounded below by 0? What garantees that the function will be bounded above as well? Thanks

Comment: I mean in the proof crostul concludes g->0 hence it is bounded and so constant but g->0 means g>=0 which is not an upper bound?

Comment: if you apply liouville to the reciprocal of $g$ the result goes over to the bounded below case.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are making the hypothesis that $f$ is holomorphic. Suppose $f$ misses $a\in\Bbb C$. By hypothesis on $f$, there exists $R>0$ such that 
$$\forall z\in\Bbb C,\;|z|\geq R\Longrightarrow |f(z)|\geq |a|+1$$
And $f\left(\overline{D(0,R)}\right)$ is compact and doesn't contain $a$ so that there exists $r>0$ with $D(a,r)\subset\Bbb C\setminus f\left(\overline{D(0,R)}\right)$. Then 
$$g(z)=\frac1{f(z)-a}$$
is bounded holomorphic on $\Bbb C$, thus constant which contradicts the hypothesis on $f$.

Comment: What does the notation of the bar over D mean?

Comment: Also how do you conclude that there is r>0 s.t D(a,r) is outside of f(D(0,R))? I ask since is a single point, why cant points near it not be inside f(D(0,R))?Is it because f is continuous?

Comment: @Socchi for any $a\in\Bbb C$ and $\rho>0$ set $\overline{D(a,\rho)}=\lbrace z\in\Bbb C\mid|z-a|\leq\rho\rbrace$The $r$ comes from the fact that $\overline{D(0,R)}$ is compact, so is its image under the continuous map $f$, and so it is closed, i.e. its complement is open, and $a$ lies in that complement.

Answer (score 2):

The condition that $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$ says that $\infty$ is a pole of $f$. It is not hard to prove that if $f$ is an entire function with a pole at $\infty$, then $f$ is a polynomial. Since any polynomial is surjective it follows that $f(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Is there a proof?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f$ is entire, suppose $f$ doesn't attain all values, for example suppose $f(z)\neq a$. Then $h(z):=f(z)-a$ has no zeros. This means that $h(z)$ has an analytic logorithm, so that we can write be that $h(z)=e^{g(z)}$, for $g$ analytic. However $|h(z)|\rightarrow\infty$ for $|z|\rightarrow\infty$, which means that $g(z)$ has to be bounded below, meaning it's constant. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Oh come on, that's a bit of a sledgehammer approach!

Comment: @Chappers: agreed, simplified now.

Comment: Thanks but Why does h(z) need to be bounded below? And why does that imply its a constant? Sorry I'm just new at this sort of thing.

Comment: Ah ok if its bounded below or above then by louisville its a constant?